# How to obtain API Key for Google App Engine WHAT IS API KEY

Tags: android, google-app-engine, api-key

I looked everywhere for a week there is no place that there is said what is API Key is and how to obtain(get) it?

What I suppose to write in `API Key` and`Project Number` fields?

[image]

Comment: When you clicked the "For more information, click here" link in the dialog, what did that tell you?

Comment: @CommonsWare Did not tell me how to get the API Key.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it Project ID, Label or what?

Comment: @CommonsWare You did not help, you asked me to follow link that I followed 50 times by now, I really try to find out it for week.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae -- see step #4. I found this in 30 seconds by searching on `google app engine api key` on a major search engine.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even taught I get errors when generating backend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695772/wst-jsdt-web-has-not-been-defined-while-generating-google-app-engine-backend

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~YOURAPPID/apiui/credential

to the Public API access section.  (Make sure you change the "YOURAPPID" section to your own.)  If you don't already see the API key, click on the "CREATE NEW KEY" button.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure how this took you a week, but you can find information on `API-KEYS` for `Google App Engine` on the [Google for developers website](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys). With your Google account, you can set everything up in minutes in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).